# Why does using regular expression to check the input from user give me error message in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I am a new Python learner. I wrote the code below  which is for a program that reads a number (eg. 1234), adds up all the digits (the result would be 10), and displays the result.

It works if I remove the regular expression part. However, I would like to know why the code does not work with it?

```
import re

numbers= int(input("Enter a number e.g. 1234 :"))
n=re.match('(\d+)', number)

if n:
    total = 0 
    for number in numbers: 
        total += number
        print ("The total sum is:",total)

else:
    print ("invalid input!")
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

re.match returns a match instance:

```
>>> import re
>>> number='123'  # just an example
>>> re.match('(\d+)', number)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 3), match='123'>
```

What you need is what was matched:

```
>>> re.match('(\d+)', number).group()
'123'
```

An example of why the regex might be useful is the case of removing unwanted strings.  For example:

```
>>> number='123 kg'
>>> re.match('(\d+)', number).group()
'123'
```

To sum over digits:

```
>>> number='123 kg'
>>> digits = re.match('(\d+)', number).group()
>>> sum(int(c) for c in digits)
6
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is for matching and comparing against strings.  When you convert the input to `int` regex will fail because it is no longer comparing to a string.

Also, you cannot iterate over an integer.  I think what you want to do is to check if the string input is all digits, then iterate over the digits in the string, convert them to ints, and sum as you go.

try this:

```
import re

number= input("Enter a number of variable length e.g. 73618 :")
n=re.match('(\d+)', number)

if n:
    total = 0 
    for digit in number: 
        total += int(digit)
        print ("The total sum of digits is:",total)

else:
    print ("Error! Make sure you only use numbers")
```

Answer (score 0):

As per python docs :

```
re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)
```

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the
>   regular expression pattern, return a corresponding MatchObject
>   instance. Return None if the string does not match the pattern

So what you need to do here is check if the returned value from regex is not `None`.

ie, `if n is not None:`

Answer (score 0):

The other answers got pieces right, but it really is much simpler than what you're making it anyway.

You're getting the error because re.match works with strings, not integers, so you need:

```
number = input("Enter a number of variable length e.g. 73618 :")
```

Also, if re does not match, it will return None. None is not the same as False:

```
if n is not None: ...
```

It also doesn't work if you mix numbers and letters (e.g. 9f). The solution is very simple though. You don't need to use re at all:

```
number = input("Enter a number of variable length e.g. 73618 :")

if number.isdigit():
    total = 0 
        for digit in number: 
            total += digit
            print ("The total sum of digits is:",total)
else:
    print("Error! Make sure you only use numbers")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only trying to enter a single number, a regular expression might be a bit overkill here. When you use Python's `int()` function to convert a string into a number, it will give you an error if the string contains letters. You can catch this using exception handling as follows:

```
try:        
    number_string = input("Enter a number of variable length e.g. 73618 : ")
    number = int(number_string)  # try and convert the string into a number
    total = 0 
    for digit in number_string: 
        total += int(digit)
    print ("The total sum of digits is:", total)    

except ValueError as e:
    print ("Error! Make sure you only use numbers")
```

You could also make use of Python's `sum()` function to help with the totalling:

```
try:        
    number_string = input("Enter a number of variable length e.g. 73618 : ")
    number = int(number_string)  # try and convert the string into a number

    total = sum(int(digit) for digit in number_string) 
    print ("The total sum of digits is:", total)    

except ValueError as e:
    print ("Error! Make sure you only use numbers")
```